# Implementing error function in Octave

Tags: octave

I am a complete beginner at programming and I'm having trouble with implementing the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) for my homework assignment. My `erf(x)` works fine for values of `x` from 0 to 2.0 but doesn't work for higher values as it should. The table for the proper values is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Table_of_values).

```
function y = erf (z) 
    konst = 2/(pi^0.5);
    vsota=0;

    n=0;
    while n <= 500;
        vsota = vsota + ((-1)^n)*(z^(2*n+1))/(factorial(n)*(2*n+1));
        n=n+1;
    end
    y=konst*vsota;
end
```

Please help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope!

Comment: So you're supposed to _implement_ the error function, and not just use the built-in one? http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/erf.html

Comment: Yes, I actually need to do and compare three implementations of the error function, the three different equations for the implementations are [**here**](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/835/enacbepic.png/)

I'm having problem with no. 1 (described in the OP) and no.2 - (I'm not sure how to get the double factorial I need in the second equation -- I guess I can use an inbuilt function for that part of the task)

(T_T)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe octave is having trouble evaluating `factorial()` of large numbers. I got good results using `n <= 170` in Python.